# How to integrate springsecurity in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, spring-security

Is there a possible way to integrate SpringSecurity in GWT?

I want to know if GWT can interact with SpringSecurity. I want to understand the interaction between the client and server.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608706/how-to-integrate-spring-security-and-gwt

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Here are a few tutorials

http://seewah.blogspot.com/2009/02/gwt-and-spring-security.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html

You can find more with a quick google.

Comment: @Pang I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Keep everything security related behind your server facade where it belongs and where it basically has nothing to do with GWT itself. On the client side, you need only to retrieve username and password from the user in order to send them to the server.